# look up a word in Dictionary.app in Terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, dictionary

Is there a bash or applescript to look up a word in `/Applications/Dictionary.app` from a Terminal window ?

```
open -a /Applications/Dictionary.app/ --args word
```

ignores --args, says "type a word to look up"

[Mac Dictionary improvements](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10798/mac-dictionary-improvements) suggests <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> however I'm looking to launch the full app, not just the small popover.

Comment: Instead of the "more" button you just click the dictionary's name in the pop-up to open the search in the dictionary application.

Comment: Thanks everybody, [there's_more_than_one_way_to_skin_a_cat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there's_more_than_one_way_to_skin_a_cat)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use...

```
open dict://my_word
```

...which will open the Dictionary application and lookup the string `my_word`. If you want to use multiple words use something like `open dict://"Big Bang Theory"`.

There's no output in the Terminal though.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a list of open magicprefix:... someplace  ?

Comment: @Denis I don't know of a source that specifically collects undocumented command options for `open`. But generally speaking, http://hints.macworld.com/ is a well known source for hidden gems. I also used to know a different source which collects undocumented `defaults write` commands, but I can't remember it just know and Google did not help me either...

Comment: I made a brief summary of `open` on SuperUser a while ago http://superuser.com/questions/4368/os-x-equivalent-of-windows-run-box/4383#4383

Comment: @denis the system maintains a database of all the prefixes that all the apps installed have told it how to handle. If you can think of a practical use for knowing that tidbit, asking a full question would be awesome.

Answer (score 24):

Using the Python Objective-C bindings, you could create just a small python script to get it from the built in OS X Dictionary. [Here's a post](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=26675) that details this script"

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from CoreServices import DictionaryServices


def main():
    try:
        searchword = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        errmsg = 'You did not enter any terms to look up in the Dictionary.'
        print(errmsg)
        sys.exit()
    wordrange = (0, len(searchword))
    dictresult = DictionaryServices.DCSCopyTextDefinition(None, searchword, wordrange)
    if not dictresult:
        errmsg = "'%s' not found in Dictionary." % (searchword)
        print(errmsg)
    else:
        print(dictresult)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Save that to `dict.py`, and then just run `python dict.py dictation`

[image]

[Check out the post](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=26675) for more instructions on making it accessable all across your terminal.

Comment: I've added some string replacements to simulate line breaks.. seems to work ok although I haven't tested it extensively: https://gist.github.com/lambdamusic/bdd56b25a5f547599f7f

Comment: Any why I get this string without linebreaks?

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution using Swift 4.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift
import Foundation

if (CommandLine.argc < 2) {
    print("Usage: dictionary word")
}else{
    let argument = CommandLine.arguments[1]
    let result = DCSCopyTextDefinition(nil, argument as CFString, CFRangeMake(0, argument.count))?.takeRetainedValue() as String?
    print(result ?? "")
}
```

1. save this as `dict.swift`
2. add permission by `chmod +x dict.swift`
3. lookup dictionary

   - run with interpreter `./dict.swift word`
   - build by compiler `swiftc dict.swift` and run `./dict word`

Comment: Thanks! This works, but it's worth noting that this only returns the first match in all active dictionaries: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1446842-dcscopytextdefinition . It seems impossible to get all matches using the current API.

Answer (score 4):

I was also going to suggest `open dict://word`, but Google's dictionary API also uses the New Oxford American Dictionary:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "open-uri"
require "json"
require "cgi"

ARGV.each { |word|
  response = open("http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dict_api.callbacks.id100&q=#{CGI.escape(word)}&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr,de").read
  results = JSON.parse(response.sub(/dict_api.callbacks.id100\(/, "").sub(/,200,null\)$/, ""))
  next unless results["primaries"]
  results["primaries"][0]["entries"].select { |e| e["type"] == "meaning" }.each { |entry|
    puts word + ": " + entry["terms"][0]["text"].gsub(/x3c\/?(em|i|b)x3e/, "").gsub("x27", "'")
  }
}
```

Comment: That Google API is deprecated and returns 404. Looks like http://www.dictionaryapi.com/ could work, just have to make a login.

Answer (score 3):

The updated code from David Perace answer, add some colors and new lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import re
from DictionaryServices import *

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

def main():
    try:
        searchword = sys.argv[1].decode('utf-8')
    except IndexError:
        errmsg = 'You did not enter any terms to look up in the Dictionary.'
        print errmsg
        sys.exit()
    wordrange = (0, len(searchword))
    dictresult = DCSCopyTextDefinition(None, searchword, wordrange)
    if not dictresult:
        errmsg = "'%s' not found in Dictionary." % (searchword)
        print errmsg.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        result = dictresult.encode('utf-8')
        result = re.sub(r'\|(.+?)\|', bcolors.HEADER + r'/\1/' + bcolors.ENDC, result)
        result = re.sub(r'▶', '\n\n ' + bcolors.FAIL + '▶ ' + bcolors.ENDC, result)
        result = re.sub(r'• ', '\n   ' + bcolors.OKGREEN + '• ' + bcolors.ENDC, result)
        result = re.sub(r'(‘|“)(.+?)(’|”)', bcolors.WARNING + r'“\2”' + bcolors.ENDC, result)
        print result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

checkout this github repo:
https://github.com/aztack/osx-dictionary

install： `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takumakei/osx-dictionary/master/osx-dictionary.rb --HEAD`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I installed `dict` from `homebrew` so now when I use `dict` from command line it's working simply. I needed this one for my custom emacs configuration

Answer (score 2):

Try [Dictionary OSX](https://github.com/odlp/dictionary-osx) (I made this after getting stuck with other answers and wanting a non-Python solution). It uses the definitions from `Dictionary.app`.

```
dictionary cat
# cat 1 |kat| ▶noun 1 a small domesticated carnivorous mammal with soft fur...
```

It uses [DictionaryKit](https://github.com/mattt/DictionaryKit), a wrapper for the private Dictionary Services available on OSX. There's interesting background information about how this works on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/dictionary-services/).

Answer (score 2):

I use this alias:

```
alias dict='f(){ open "dict://${1}"; unset -f f; }; f'
```

Explanation here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366683

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post looking for a similar thing. Wasn't happy with the options available so made simple script. Its a terminal based thesaurus with text to speech. May be of interest ...

https://github.com/aefty/thes

Answer (score 0):

Look in the following thread to find out how to use Dictionary.app in the Terminal:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2679911?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score -1):

[Here's](https://github.com/shalomfriss/define) a super straightforward thing I threw together.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If the link breaks, the answer becomes worthless.